# How to show the payeer wallet balance throught payeer payment API?

Tags: php

I had added this code to my payeer site:

```
<?
require_once('cpayeer.php');
$accountNumber = 'P1009239954';
$apiId = '1045692239';
$apiKey = '****************';
$payeer = new CPayeer($accountNumber, $apiId, $apiKey);
if ($payeer->isAuth())
{
    $arBalance = $payeer->getBalance();
    echo '<pre>'.print_r($arBalance, true).'</pre>';
}
else
{
    echo '<pre>'.print_r($payeer->getErrors(), true).'</pre>';
}
?>
```

Replacing `'key'` with my payeer key should show my payeer balance into my site. But it doesn't. How could I do?

Answer (score 0):

You Cant get until you have not access of **merchant**

go **merchant** create merchant store

verify **merchant**

create apID
apKey

Now go to masspayout tab ->ADD api user
you have to provide your IP

And api key..
Note, you have to change your api key after every ip

mean ip change api key change

enjoy